# Light-4j server stops responding to HTTP GET or POST

Tags: light-4j

I am facing some issue with ***1.6.5*** version.
Sometimes the server stops replying to my http rest calls. The `tcpdump` indicated proper tcp hand-shake..and http request going. But no response comes from server.
This is basic http get call and no processing on the server is happening. Server should receive this call and should reply back with 200 OK response.
If I restart the server, it starts working again. This issue is intermittent.

Any pointers would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting the question on this site. It is easier to search than in other places.

When the server stops responding to the exact same request after a while, it is very possible that there are some memory leak or connection leak in the business logic. You can put some debug info on the suspected code block or run the application in debug mode in an IDE. Light-4j application is just a plain Java SE application and you can debug it in the IDE to pinpoint the issue easily.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply. I my case, the issue might have been synchronized section of business logic. One of the REST call was in the critical section and did not return which resulted in blocking of the new REST calls. I am still watching this issue.

Vikram